# A api do prestashop parou de autenticar

Tags: php, htaccess, e-commerce

Após uma migração do servidor, minha api parou de passar o usuário na variável `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`

Segue o meu htaccess e script:

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

FileETag INode MTime Size
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

O meu script em PHP:

```
<?php
/*
* 2007-2014 PrestaShop
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
* needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
*
*  @author PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
*  @copyright  2007-2014 PrestaShop SA
*  @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
*  International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
*/
ob_start();

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/config.inc.php');

// Cart is needed for some requests
Context::getContext()->cart = new Cart();
//set http auth headers for apache+php-cgi work around
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) && preg_match('/Basic\s+(.*)$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], $matches))
{
    list($name, $password) = explode(':', base64_decode($matches[1]));
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = strip_tags($name);
}

//set http auth headers for apache+php-cgi work around if variable gets renamed by apache
if (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) && preg_match('/Basic\s+(.*)$/i', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], $matches))
{
    list($name, $password) = explode(':', base64_decode($matches[1]));
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = strip_tags($name);
}

// Use for image management (using the POST method of the browser to simulate the PUT method)
$method = isset($_REQUEST['ps_method']) ? $_REQUEST['ps_method'] : $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
    $key = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
elseif (isset($_GET['ws_key']))
    $key = $_GET['ws_key'];
else
{
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Welcome to PrestaShop Webservice, please enter the authentication key as the login. No password required."');
    die;
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['xml']))
{
    // if a XML is in POST
    $input_xml = stripslashes($_REQUEST['xml']);
}
else
{
    // if no XML
    $input_xml = NULL;

    // if a XML is in PUT or in POST
    if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') || ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'))
    {
        $putresource = fopen("php://input", "r");
        while ($putData = fread($putresource, 1024))
            $input_xml .= $putData;
        fclose($putresource);
    }
}

$params = $_GET;
unset($params['url']);

$class_name = WebserviceKey::getClassFromKey($key);
$bad_class_name = false;
if (!class_exists($class_name))
{
    $class_name = 'WebserviceRequest';
    $bad_class_name = true;
}
// fetch the request
WebserviceRequest::$ws_current_classname = $class_name;
$request = call_user_func(array($class_name, 'getInstance'));
$result = $request->fetch($key, $method, $_GET['url'], $params, $bad_class_name, $input_xml);

// display result
if (ob_get_length() != 0)
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript'); // Useful for debug...

// Manage cache
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_LOCAL_CONTENT_SHA1']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_LOCAL_CONTENT_SHA1'] == $result['content_sha1']) {
    $result['status'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 304 Not Modified';
}

if (is_array($result['headers']))
    foreach ($result['headers'] as $param_value)
    {
        header($param_value);
    }
if (isset($result['type']))
{
//  header($result['content_sha1']);
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_LOCAL_CONTENT_SHA1']) || $_SERVER['HTTP_LOCAL_CONTENT_SHA1'] != $result['content_sha1'])
    {
        echo $result['content'];
    }

}
ob_end_flush();
```

Ele simplesmente não está mais passando o PHP_AUTH_USER, como faço para resolver?

Comment: roda mas ta em fastcgi

Comment: php 5.5 prestashop 1.6+
he modulo da bling funcionava normal ate eles mudarem a instancia no sevridor

Comment: Consulte o desenvolvedor do módulo. Explique que está rodando sob fastcgi que eles saberão o que fazer. Mostre isso a eles ou tente você mesmo adaptar: http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCFV-7266 Veja isso também: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663520/php-auth-user-not-set

Comment: eu testei no meu servidor com fast cgi e funciono no servidor do cara nao rola :( ta com mesmo php mesmo apache sei la q ta rolando

Comment: Observe que existe um "workaround" (gambiarra) para o caso de rodar sob php-cgi. Mas isso pode não funcionar sob um fast-cgi ou php-fpm, por exemplo. Consulte esses links que te passei para tentar resolver por conta própria e informe ao desenvolvedor do módulo pois devem prestar suporte.

Comment: tentei usar todos os codigos passados nos posts e nenhum funcionou.

Comment: Há inconsistências nesse script do módulo pois nem ao menos checa o retorno de `php_sapi_name()` para determinar se deve ou não entrar na condicional do php-cgi. Execute isso echo `php_sapi_name()` nesse servidor com erro e poste na pergunta o que exatamente retornou. Poste também na pegunta o que e como tentou implementar dos códigos nos links que passei.